# Why does Python static typing not produce TypeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-typing

I found out that Python is intending to support static typing, but it still in beta phase.
I tried the following code with python 3.4.3:

```
def somme(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
```

the syntax is supported but I did not get the expected result.
If I type `somme('1', '3')` I get `'13'`.

I would have expected to get a `TypeError` exception saying `int variable expected`.

Has anyone an idea why it's not working ?

Comment: The typing is just hints, it's not enforced.

Comment: BTW, what you are describing is run-time type checking *not* static type checking which is done at compile time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In reality, you aren't supposed to get static typing here. The code you wrote is actually a form of easy documentation and "type hinting", as explained [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). To quote that PEP:

> While these annotations are available at runtime through the usual **annotations** attribute, no type checking happens at runtime . Instead, the proposal assumes the existence of a separate off-line type checker which users can run over their source code voluntarily. Essentially, such a type checker acts as a very powerful linter. (While it would of course be possible for individual users to employ a similar checker at run time for Design By Contract enforcement or JIT optimization, those tools are not yet as mature.)

So in other words, it was developed to support a third party library that will actually do the checking for you. I've never bothered with static typing in Python, although a friend of mine often uses [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/) to achieve it. This might be what you're looking for.

**EDIT:**

**installation :** MyPy can be installed using pip:

```
pip install mypy-lang
```

**Usage :**  you can type-check your program as follow:

```
~$ mypy my_script.py
```

Answer (score 13):

The function annotations there are *annotations*, nothing more. They're documentation about intended usage. Like it says in [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), the mechanism provides a single, standard way to specify function parameters and return values, replacing a variety of ad-hoc tools and libraries.

But as it goes on to say:

> Function annotations are nothing more than a way of associating
>   arbitrary Python expressions with various parts of a function at
>   compile-time.
>
> By itself, Python does not attach any particular meaning or
>   significance to annotations. Left to its own, Python simply makes
>   these expressions available as described in Accessing Function
>   Annotations below.

[PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) adds more conventions and tools for using these annotations to mark types, adopted in Python 3.5. But still there is no runtime checking in the language itself: it "includes support for off-line type checkers such as mypy".

That is, after using these annotations, you can run third-party type checkers to check if your code adheres to the annotated types. Building these annotations into the language should make it easier for various IDEs to provide this service.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I'm talking about.

Comment: @AymenGasmi: ...No, really, that's what you're talking about. The `: int` after the parameters of your function, and the `-> int` part at the end, yes?

Comment: Yes I got it, this explained why the syntax was correct but what I was really looking for is the mypy. I though that the type checker is now built-in but it seems to be not yet and it should still be used as 3rd Party. @chrislessard answer is what I'm exactly looking for. But thank you anyway :)